# How to call another POM.xml from main POM.xml

Tags: maven

Basically I have more than 2 pom.xml in the project. Either I can call all one by one from other pom.xml like Ant or I can run all the pom.xml in a sequence.

But I am not sure how can I achieve this. I am new to maven.

Comment: Please explain why you have two pom files and why it is necessary... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there can only be one POM file per project and you cannot "call" other POM files.

Answer (score 1):

others may still be looking for multi-module project: https://www.baeldung.com/maven-multi-module Each module inside Super POM can have own POM

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34634124)